# How to use a resource for 2 different addresses in different environments in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I developed a `SAPUI5` application in WEB IDE. When I am testing my application inside of the `WEB IDE` I want to load a resource from URL1 and when I deploy it on a SAP ABAP Repository I want to use URL2 for that resource. The question is that how can I detect the in which environment my application is run? In HCP or in ABAP? One possibility is to check the page URL, but is there a built in function in SAPUI5 library to be used for this purpose? I don't mean a built in function for checking the url but a function that is more stable than checking the url. Because checking the url maybe produce unstable situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is not such a function.

If you don't want to to check the URL just define a new URL param which you can append to your URL and then access the parameter in your code:

YOURURL/index.html?someParameter=WHATEVERYOUWANT

```
 var someParameter = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters().get("someParameter");
```